# How to write a rails helper for a bootstrap tool tip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a helper to insert a bootstrap tool tip into a link.  I am trying

```
  def tool_tip(text)
    { data: { toggle: :tooltip }, title: text }
  end
```

This works if it is a simple link i.e.

but if there are further modifiers it does not work i.e

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'side_menu_link', tool_tip('Your Home') %>
```

it gives an error

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
...enu_link', tool_tip('Your Home') );@output_buffer.safe_append='
```

presumably because of the way it is being parsed. Is there a way I can do this?

Possibly related to this parsing, if I try to do a helper that adds placement e.g.

```
   def tool_tip(text, position)
     { data: { toggle: :tooltip, placement: position }, title: text }
   end
```

it does not work at all.

Comment: What do you mean with _if there are further modifiers it does not work_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})

The [link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) method takes the html_options parameter after the url parameter. html_options is a hash parameter. The application crashes because you send two arguments after the url: `{ class: 'side_menu_link' }, tool_tip('Your Home')`

This should work:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path, tool_tip('Your Home').merge(class: 'side_menu_link') %>
```